# VBA: How to remove Decimal Point from values on Y Axis of Stock OHLC Chart

Tags: excel, vba, yaxis

VBA Experts.
I have written VBA Code for existing OHLC Stock Chart. Everything is fine; except Y Axis Values with Decimal (like 14083.23 to 14683.23) while I want Round Number (14083 to 14683). For this I have used RoundUp and RoundDown Function but still Decimal point NOT disappeared. Could you please, suggest where am making mistake.
Thank you. The code is as follow.

Sub Min75Candlestick()

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet

    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("75Min")

Dim ws2 As Worksheet

    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Exhibit")

Dim LastRow As Long

    LastRow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim RngSt As Long

    RngSt = LastRow - 59

Dim RngEnd As Long

    RngEnd = LastRow + 15

Dim MyRng As Range

    Set MyRng = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(RngSt, 1), ws1.Cells(RngEnd, 5))

Dim OHLCRng

    Set OHLCRng = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(RngSt, 2), ws1.Cells(RngEnd, 5))

Dim OHLCMaxRng As Long

    OHLCMaxRng = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(OHLCRng)

Dim RoundMax As Long

    RoundMax = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(OHLCMaxRng, 0)

Dim OHLCMinRng As Long

    OHLCMinRng = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(OHLCRng)

Dim RoundMin As Long

    RoundMin = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(OHLCMinRng, 0)

Dim Padding As Double

    Padding = 0.005

Dim OHLCChart As ChartObject

    Set OHLCChart = ws2.ChartObjects(1)

        With OHLCChart.Chart

            .SetSourceData MyRng

            .Axes (xlValue)

                With .Axes(xlValue)

                    .MaximumScale = RoundMax * (1 + Padding) '+ (RoundMax * 1 / 100)

                    .MinimumScale = RoundMin * (1 - Padding) '- (RoundMin * 1 / 100)

                End With

            .ChartTitle.Text = "75Min Candlestick chart"

            .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = False

            .PlotArea.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(242, 242, 242)

            .Parent.Name = "OHLC Chart"

        End With
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1):

Thanks All.
The final code is as following...
Sub Min75Candlestick()

```
Const padding As Double = 0.005

Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim MyRng As Range, OHLCRng As Range
Dim LastRow As Long, RngSt As Long, RngEnd As Long
Dim RoundMax As Long, RoundMin As Long

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("75Min")
LastRow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
RngSt = LastRow - 59
RngEnd = LastRow + 15

Set MyRng = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(RngSt, 1), ws1.Cells(RngEnd, 5))
Set OHLCRng = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(RngSt, 2), ws1.Cells(RngEnd, 5))

With Application.WorksheetFunction
    RoundMax = .RoundUp(.Max(OHLCRng), 0)
    RoundMin = .RoundDown(.Min(OHLCRng), 0)
End With

Dim OHLCChart As ChartObject
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Exhibit")
Set OHLCChart = ws2.ChartObjects(1)
With OHLCChart.Chart
    .Parent.Name = "OHLC Chart"
    .ChartTitle.Text = "75Min Candlestick chart"
    .SetSourceData MyRng
    .Axes xlValue
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = False
    With .Axes(xlValue)
         .MaximumScale = RoundMax * (1 + padding) 
         .MinimumScale = RoundMin * (1 - padding) 
         .TickLabels.NumberFormat = "#,##0"
    End With
    .PlotArea.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(242, 242, 242)
End With
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Add `.TickLabels.NumberFormat = "#,##0"`

```vb
Sub Min75Candlestick()

    Const padding As Double = 0.005

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim MyRng As Range, OHLCRng As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long, RngSt As Long, RngEnd As Long
    Dim RoundMax As Long, RoundMin As Long

    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("75Min")
    LastRow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    RngSt = LastRow - 59
    RngEnd = LastRow + 15

    Set MyRng = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(RngSt, 1), ws1.Cells(RngEnd, 5))
    Set OHLCRng = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(RngSt, 2), ws1.Cells(RngEnd, 5))

    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        RoundMax = .RoundUp(.Max(OHLCRng), 0)
        RoundMin = .RoundDown(.Min(OHLCRng), 0)
    End With
    
    Dim OHLCChart As ChartObject
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Exhibit")
    Set OHLCChart = ws2.ChartObjects(1)
    With OHLCChart.Chart
        .Parent.Name = "OHLC Chart"
        .ChartTitle.Text = "75Min Candlestick chart"
        .SetSourceData MyRng
        .Axes xlValue
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = False
        With .Axes(xlValue)
             .MaximumScale = RoundMax * (1 + padding) '+ (RoundMax * 1 / 100)
             .MinimumScale = RoundMin * (1 - padding) '- (RoundMin * 1 / 100)
             .TickLabels.NumberFormat = "#,##0"
        End With
        .PlotArea.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(242, 242, 242)
    End With
End Sub
```